# How can i make it more simple and easy to read? in my tic tac toe python project

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, python-sockets

i made a function to check if there is a win in my socket tic tac toe game, the problem is, its to hard to read.

Is there a way i can make it more simple? i thought about for loops but i think it wont be right in my case

```
    if board[0][0] == board[1][0] and board[1][0] == board[2][0]:
        if board[0][0] == 'X':
            client_sockets[0].send("you win")
            client_sockets[1].send("you lose")
        else:
            client_sockets[1].send("you win")
            client_sockets[0].send("you lose")
    if board[0][1] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][1]:
        if board[0][1] == 'X':
            client_sockets[0].send("you win")
            client_sockets[1].send("you lose")
        else:
            client_sockets[1].send("you win")
            client_sockets[0].send("you lose")
    if board[0][2] == board[1][2] and board[1][2] == board[2][2]:
        if board[0][0] == 'X':
            client_sockets[0].send("you win")
            client_sockets[1].send("you lose")
        else:
            client_sockets[1].send("you win")
            client_sockets[0].send("you lose")
```

and so on...

Comment: A link can't be used as an answer, but I would suggest you to check the code of my tic-tac-toe project here https://github.com/FLAK-ZOSO/Tris

Comment: This is off topic for Stackoverflow, as it's opinionated. Try asking at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very cool project that uses sockets - https://github.com/Suvoo/TicTacToe-Using-Socket-Server

try this snippet snippet:

```
import random


class TicTacToe:

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []

    def create_board(self):
        for i in range(3):
            row = []
            for j in range(3):
                row.append('-')
            self.board.append(row)

    def get_random_first_player(self):
        return random.randint(0, 1)

    def fix_spot(self, row, col, player):
        self.board[row][col] = player

    def is_player_win(self, player):
        win = None

        n = len(self.board)

        # checking rows
        for i in range(n):
            win = True
            for j in range(n):
                if self.board[i][j] != player:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                return win

        # checking columns
        for i in range(n):
            win = True
            for j in range(n):
                if self.board[j][i] != player:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                return win

        # checking diagonals
        win = True
        for i in range(n):
            if self.board[i][i] != player:
                win = False
                break
        if win:
            return win

        win = True
        for i in range(n):
            if self.board[i][n - 1 - i] != player:
                win = False
                break
        if win:
            return win
        return False

        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item == '-':
                    return False
        return True

    def is_board_filled(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item == '-':
                    return False
        return True

    def swap_player_turn(self, player):
        return 'X' if player == 'O' else 'O'

    def show_board(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                print(item, end=" ")
            print()

    def start(self):
        self.create_board()

        player = 'X' if self.get_random_first_player() == 1 else 'O'
        while True:
            print(f"Player {player} turn")

            self.show_board()

            # taking user input
            row, col = list(
                map(int, input("Enter row and column numbers to fix spot: ").split()))
            print()

            # fixing the spot
            self.fix_spot(row - 1, col - 1, player)

            # checking whether current player is won or not
            if self.is_player_win(player):
                print(f"Player {player} wins the game!")
                break

            # checking whether the game is draw or not
            if self.is_board_filled():
                print("Match Draw!")
                break

            # swapping the turn
            player = self.swap_player_turn(player)

        # showing the final view of board
        print()
        self.show_board()


# starting the game
tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe()
tic_tac_toe.start()
```

[more info](https://geekflare.com/tic-tac-toe-python-code/)

Comment: is there a way i can make my own code more simple? i dont want to use class in this stage + my code is using sockets

Answer (score 0):

You could encode the current state of the board in a string instead of a nested list.
So for example,

```
board = [['O', 'X', ''], ['O', 'X', ''], ['X', 'X', '']]
```

could also be encoded as:

```
sboard = "OX OX XX "
```

(Replacing all the list by tuples would also work.)

Next, you write two functions:

```
def xwins():
    client_sockets[0].send("you win")
    client_sockets[1].send("you lose")

def owins():
    client_sockets[1].send("you win")
    client_sockets[0].send("you lose")
```

Finally, you create a dictionary of all game ending boards.
This is possible because strings are *hashable*, and can therefore be used as dictionary keys.

```
victory = {
    "OX OX XX ": xwins,
    "OX OX OX ": ywins,
    # et cetera
}
```

Note how we *reference* the functions, but do *not* call them here.

After every move, you create a new `sboard` string, based on the old one and user input.

If the board is a winning move, you call the correct function via the dictionary:

```
if sboard in victory:
    victory[sboard]()
    exit_game()
# else continue playing.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your 3rd condition under `if board[0][2] == 'X'...`, you checking checking `if board[0][0] == 'X'`.

This highlights why all this code duplication is error prone.  Hence the DRY principle.

When you have repeated code like this, think 'indirection'.  Data structures and meta-data are the key to writing generic code that doesn't repeat itself.

For example, lets say you have a list of coordinate triplets that correspond to the 8 "lines" of your tic-tac-toe board.  You could loop through this list and only implement the condition once using the coordinate triplets:

```
winCoords = [ [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)],
              [(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)],
              [(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)],
              [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)],
              [(0,1),(1,1),(2,1)],
              [(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)],
              [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)],
              [(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)] ]

for (r0,c0),(r1,c1),(r2,c2) in winCoords:
    if board[r0][c0] == board[r1][c1] == board[r2][c2]:
        winner,loser = (1,0) if board[r0][c0] == "X" else (0,1)
        client_sockets[winner].send("you win")
        client_sockets[loser].send("you lose")
        break
```

*Note that your sample code doesn't describe how you handle unplayed lines where all 3 values will be equal but neither "X" nor "O", which would seemingly result in a winning condition for 'O' (unless the default values are all distinct)*